# Console weight converter user choice

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and have made a few working console applications such as Hello World and a BMI Calculator.

I'm trying to make a weight converter from imperial to metric and vice versa now, but I'm having trouble letting the user choose which they would like to do. This is the segment of code I am struggling with:

```
decimal pounds;
decimal poundsconverted;
decimal kilo;
decimal kiloconverted;
string choice;

Console.WriteLine ("Press 1 to convert from imperial to metric");
Console.WriteLine ("Press 2 to convert from metric to imperial");
choice = Console.ReadLine();

if (choice (1))
    Console.WriteLine ("Please enter the weight you would like to convert in pounds (lbs) ex. 140");
    pounds = Convert.ToDecimal (Console.ReadLine());
    poundsconverted=pounds/2.2;
    Console.WriteLine("The weight in kilograms is:{0:F3}", poundsconverted);

if (choice (2))
    Console.WriteLine ("Please enter the weight you would like to conver in kilograms (kg) ex. 80");
    kilo = Convert.ToDecimal (Console.ReadLine());
    kiloconverted=pounds*2.2;
    Console.WriteLine("The weight in pounds is:{0:F3}", kiloconverted);
```

My problem is with the `if` statements. I have tried multiple formats but to no avail. Is there a better method to do this? is it possible with `if` statements?

Comment: You you trying to check whether it's `==` to a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `switch/ case` or `if/else` here is the sample for switch/case

```
decimal pounds;
decimal poundsconverted;
decimal kilo;
decimal kiloconverted;
string choice;


Console.WriteLine ("Press 1 to convert from imperial to metric");
Console.WriteLine ("Press 2 to convert from metric to imperial");
choice = Console.ReadLine();
switch (choice)
{
   case 1:
     Console.WriteLine ("Please enter the weight you would like to convert in pounds (lbs) ex. 140");
        pounds = Convert.ToDecimal (Console.ReadLine());
        poundsconverted=pounds/2.2;
        Console.WriteLine("The weight in kilograms is:{0:F3}", poundsconverted);
        break;
   case 2:
      Console.WriteLine ("Please enter the weight you would like to conver in kilograms (kg) ex. 80");
        kilo = Convert.ToDecimal (Console.ReadLine());
        kiloconverted=pounds*2.2;
        Console.WriteLine("The weight in pounds is:{0:F3}", kiloconverted);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped just need a few tweaks now

Answer (score 2):

Your if statements should look like:

```
if (choice  == 1)
{

}
```

If you have multiple code lines that are part of the `if` then they need to be wrapped in curly braces `{}` as above.

Answer (score 0):

```
        int pounds;           
        int kilo;              


        Console.WriteLine("Please enter (1)lb. conversion(2) kg. conversion");
        int userNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        if (userNumber == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the weight(in kilograms) you would like to convert in pounds.");
            pounds = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("The weight in pounds is:{0:F3}", pounds / 2.2);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the weight(in pounds) you would like to conver in kilograms");
            kilo = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("The weight in kilograms is:{0:F3}", kilo * .45);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```